# Doesn't recognise tag I put in

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a raycast constantly pointing and I want it to detect if it's hovering over a specific object and the way I'm doing that is detecting the tag and I gave the spicefic object a tag that no other object has and I detect what the raycast hits and if it has that tag.

'Raycasthit' does not contain a definition for 'gameObject' and no accesible extension method 'gameobject' accepting a first argument of type 'raycast hit' could be found are you missing a useage directive or an assembly reference?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Toast : MonoBehaviour
{
    Ray ray;
    RaycastHit raycastHit;


    void Update()
    {
        ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out raycastHit))
        {
            if (raycastHit.gameObject.tag=="Death")
            {
                Debug.Log("DIE OF BUTTER");         
            }
        }
       
    }
}
```

Comment: In general rather use [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html) instead of `==`. Not only is it very slightly faster (it uses hashes) but also does it log an error inc case of any typo / non-existing tag - something the `==` check silently hides  ... by the names though .. already like your app :D

Comment: You could also draw the ray in order to see whether it is actually pointing as expected `Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward * 1000);` and your target object needs to have a 3d convex collider (and if it is a trigger check your physics settings or force the Raycast to include triggers)

Comment: @derHugo The error is 'Raycasthit' does not contain a definition for 'gameObject' and no accesible extension method 'gameobject' accepting a first argument of type 'raycast hit' could be found are you missing a useage directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: well, it indeed hasn't ^^ you can go through the [`RaycastHit.transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-transform.html) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

You're trying to access `gameObject` instead of `collider`:

Use this instead:

```
raycastHit.collider.tag
```

---

Your code looks correct to me, but there are some common things that can happen.

1. Your raycast is sent from within the object so it immediately hits itself
2. The other object does not have the tag set
3. It simply does not hit, forward is another way than you're expecting

---

Some methods of debugging these issues:

1. Find out what it is hitting:

```cs
Debug.Log(raycastHit);
```

2. Look in the editor

3. Find out where it is shooting:

```cs
Debug.DrawRay(sameDirectionAsYourRaycast)
```

9/10 times, simply logging the hit makes me realize my error - which 9/10 times is that my raycast needs to ignore hitting some object in the way or move the starting point of the ray so it doesn't hit myself first.

Comment: I forgot to mention the error sorry 'Raycasthit' does not contain a definition for 'gameObject' and no accesible extension method 'gameobject' accepting a first argument of type 'raycast hit' could be found are you missing a useage directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Oh, haha. Use `raycastHit.collider.tag`

Comment: This error, which you get at IDE level, means that the object does not have the property you are trying to use. A tip is to view examples online, read the documentation or explore with intellisense (autocomplete) to understand how the objects work

Comment: A comment anwsered my question