# How To Make Raycast Come From Camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I made it draw a line like this: Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward * 1000);

But it goes up and down. how can I make this stop happening?

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Toast : MonoBehaviour
{
    Ray ray;
    RaycastHit raycastHit;


    void Update()
    {
        ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward * 1000);


        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out raycastHit))
        {
            if (raycastHit.transform.tag=="Death")
            {
                Debug.Log("DIE OF BUTTER");         
            }
        }
       
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try the code? How is that different from what you want to happen? What do you expect `transform` to mean, and why? Are you able to write code that tells you the position of the camera? If you try creating the ray with that position, does it not solve the problem? Why not? What exactly do you mean by "make the player able to select things", and *what does that have to do with* casting a ray from the camera? Of course a ray cast directly forward from the camera will tell you what is centered in the player's field of view, but *then what*?

Comment: I did that as a placeholder and when I try the code with it showing the ray I don't see it and the selecting things is just hy I'm making the code I don't need help with that.

Comment: Why should it *show* a ray just because you are casting one? Even if it did show the ray, what would you expect it to *look like*, and *why*? (Especially keeping in mind that this is a first-person perspective.)

Comment: `Debug.DrawRay` is for drawing the ray in the **SceneView**. Maybe you are rather looking for [`Camera.ScreenPointToRay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html)?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel his Debug.DrawRay() is using the same vector as his raycast so he should be able to see a ray that equates to his cast.

Comment: @derHugo The page on that didn't help me much could you help me with that more?

Comment: @RocketmanDan sure; but the ray is pointed in the same direction the camera is looking, so I wouldn't expect to see a line on the screen. It would be fully foreshortened to a point.

Comment: You should multiply the ray direction by distance.  eg.  `DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward * 20)` which draws a 20 unit ray from the origin.

Comment: @hijinxbassist also has a point - which is why [in your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76196902/7111561) I suggested to use `Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward * 1000);` ;)

Comment: What I meant by the `ScreenPointToRay` is: It sounds to me like you simply don't want to raycast where you are looking but rather where the user is pointing the mouse cursor to - `so I can make the player able to select things` - or maybe I just understood that wrong ... is this script even attached to the camera? Because otherwise it might of course not match with your cameras direction ;)

Comment: I will also copy my other comment again: `In general rather use CompareTag instead of ==. Not only is it very slightly faster (it uses hashes) but also does it log an error inc case of any typo / non-existing tag - something the == check silently hides ... by the names though .. already like your app :D`

Comment: @derHugo the Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward * 1000); it's up and forward

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes but since Debug.DrawRay doesn't render a line in the game view, only in the scene view, I assumed they were viewing it from a perspective that is not equal to that of the camera in this instance, using the scene view editor camera and not the game camera.

Comment: I fixed this problem a while ago